# show subtitles list, get id and name of each subtitles track

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to get some list of all available subtitles tracks like:

```
#1 - id, name
#2 - id, name
#3 - id, name
...
```

So list would tell how much subtitles tracks I have, show id and name of each track

Is there any `FFmpeg` option to show such list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FFmpeg** seems doesn't have such option

so we can only parse all printed data by `ffmpeg -i VIDE_FILE_NAME` (filtering out not stream text track lines)

also FFmpeg doesn't really prints that ID (it's just stream position made by FFmpeg) like MediaInfo would print

Comment: For the lazy reader: `ffprobe input.mkv 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep Stream`

Answer (score 27):

## Example

`ffprobe` command to list the stream ID and language:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -of csv=p=0 input.mkv
```

## Result

```
5,eng
6,fao
7,ain
```

This shows the stream id #5 is English, #6 is Faroese, and #7 is Ainu. See [List of ISO 639 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) (refer to 639-2/T or 639-2/B) for the language abbreviations.

## `-map` option

You can use this information to create your command. If you want the English and Ainu languages use:

```
-map 0:5 -map 0:7
```

or

```
-map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:2
```

or

```
-map 0:s:m:language:eng -map 0:s:m:language:ain
```

See the [`-map` option documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I need language (or how author of container named subtitles, doesn't matter). I wanted to work only with `FFmpeg` cause I use it for Android (https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) and there is no `FFprobe`.

Comment: @user25 `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0. I'm guessing the other tools start from 1.

Comment: ffprobe uses ISO 639-2T/639-3 (3-character) and not ISO 639-1 (2-character).
mediainfo uses ISO 639-1 language abbreviations

Comment: @MrPotatoHead Clarified in answer. I previously simply copied and pasted the link title.

Comment: Thanks. I have a similar issue where I'm trying to extract only English language subtitles specifically in SRT format. I tried ```ffprobe -v error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -of csv=p=0 <input file>```.
However, this seems to list both PGS formats as well. I did check the [ffprobe documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html), and there seems to be an option via ```txt_format``` being one of ```bitmap, text or ass```, but neither do I know how to use it, nor did I find examples. Would anyone know how to accomplish this?