# Going About Creating a Script to Detect Hard-Coded Subtitles

Tags: python, video, analyzer, subtitle

I have a ton of movies and instead of opening each one individually and checking if it has hard-coded subtitles, I would like to make a script that can do it for me. I've tried researching it on Google and on SO with no luck. I'm not even sure where to start so any help at all would be beneficial. If you already know of a way to do this, know what software I can leverage, or even just have ideas that I can start digging into, anything will help. I'm competent in Python so that would be ideal.

Comment: I'd use `ffprobe` which you can call from python ... have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160065/1569675 for an example of how to get a list of the subtitle streams (with language)

Comment: If I am misinterpreting it, let me know but that seems to be for subtitle streams which I'm not worried about. I'm concerned with detecting whether hard-coded subtitles (aka ones that you can't just deselect in a media player) exist within the video stream itself.

Comment: ah, sorry. those are actually just baked in as pixels in the video stream so aren't detectable (as far as a renderer is concerned they are just video content)